# Inputdlg does not detect line break

Tags: matlab, prompt

If I copy a text with line breaks to the prompt using the `inputdlg` command, the `Input` variable will show the text without line breaks.

```
prompt = {'Input'};
dlg_title = 'Console';
num_lines = [1 45];
defaultans = {''};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);
Input=answer{1};
```

Any suggestion to go around this problem?

Comment: What does "text with line breaks" mean? What is an input that replicates your issue?

Comment: Text with line breaks:
hello1 \n
hello2

.Text without line breaks:
hello1 hello2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to enter multi-line input (i.e. text with line breaks) into your [dialog box](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html), you can set the first value of `num_lines` to 2:

```
num_lines = [2 45];
```

This appears to allow any number of lines for your input, not just 2. In fact, *any number* greater than 1 (even fractionally so) will allow you to enter multi-line input:

```
num_lines = [1.1 45];  % Also allows multi-line input
```

The value does affect the rendering of the editable text box. The larger the number, the taller the editable text box will be. Also, a vertical scroll bar will appear on the right hand side for any value greater than 1.